# Emscripten:warning: unresolved symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE

Tags: c++, emscripten

I am learning emscripten compiler. And now I have an error when compiling this 
[source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/biv0pclyaqlljnd/snake.zip).

I use gcc and it works fine.

But, when using emscripten with this command:

```
./emcc game.cpp main.cpp painter.cpp field.cpp snake.cpp -s LEGACY_GL_EMULATION=1 -o a.html
```

I get this error.:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE`
```

What are the issues here?

Comment: I think its very vague to describe this as a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: This is more specific  then the claimed duplicate which only describes in general how to fix this type of issue but does not address issues caused by compiling c++ code on a c compiler or vise versa.

Answer (score 2):

Try `em++` isntead of `emcc`. I am not too familiar with emscripten, but the missing symbol is the `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info`, so you probably need to link the libcxxabi.